# Как из реакта обратиться к диву который в html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нужно обратиться к диву который создан в обычной HTML-разметке из реакта , для того чтоб отрендерить туда ещё несколько элементов.  Но немогу понять как это синтаксически правильно сделать ?

К примеру в `jQuery` это можно было сделать так:

```
 $("bloock").append("<div class='subblock'> <div>")
```

Нужно сделать тоже самое ток для реакта

Пример есть див с класом `"block"` , в него нужно отрендерить 3 дива с класом `"sublock"`, чтоб получилась такая разметка :

```
<div class="block"> 
  <div class="subblock"> </div>
  <div class="subblock"> </div>
  <div class="subblock"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте следующим образом. HTML:

```
<div id="root" class="block"></div>
```

JS:

```
const element = <div class="subblock"> </div>;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Полезная ссылка: [Rendering Elements](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html)

Comment: Помогло. Отлично! Спасибо